# Xamarin.Forms.ios/Visual Studio build config bug?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, buildconfiguration

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project and I need to create multiple build configs for iOS and android and depending on the build config swap out all pictures in the project but that is not the problem.

The problem is I cant create new build configs for the iOS project, for android it works fine but the iOS project even has 2 empty build configs that I cant delete nor rename, it always says "unknown error" and I tried a lot of stuff but nothing helped.

Build config manager showing the 2 empty configs:
[image: build config manager showing the 2 empty configs]

The error message that pops up when trying to delete or rename the empty configs:
[image: The error message that pops up when trying to delete or rename the empty configs]

Comment: Try to create a new blank project and check if the issue still exists .

Comment: it does already tried that sry i didnt write it before

Comment: You could open a support ticket : Help -> Send FeedBack -> Report a problem .